# Как закрыть поиск в toolbar

Tags: java, android

Пишу простенький мессенжер. Имею такую форму с диалогами:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После того как я ввожу в поиске имя нового собеседника и выбираю его, то меня перебрасывает на новую activity мне можно переписываться. Проблема в том что когда я возвращаюсь в activity с диалогами, на ней до сих пор остаёмся поисковая фраза с логином, собеседника, которого мы искали до этого. То есть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот вопрос такой: как мне закрывать/убивать эту строку поиска при возвращении на activity с диалогами?

//*********
Имею такую разметку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="@string/search_title"/>
    </menu>
```

Comment: mToolbar.getMenu().clear();

Comment: не помогло, вставил в эту строчку с событие onCreate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private SearchView searchView;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    ...
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
    ...
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    searchView.setQuery("", false);
    searchView.clearFocus();
    searchView.setIconified(true); // Если надо не только очистить, но и свернуть
}
```

Comment: Нужно добавить проверку  if(searchView != null)  иначе краш, а так всё работает

Answer (score 4):

```
private SearchView searchView;

@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Инициализация Вашего SearchView 
}

@Override 
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (searchView != null && !searchView.isIconified()) {
        searchView.setQuery("", false);
        searchView.clearFocus();
        searchView.setIconified(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: А еще можно с помощью метода `collapseActionView ()` закрыть поиск